# References in ConTeXt

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, context

I am new to ConTeXt. I've just been playing around with it to see if I can start using for my regular work.

My bibliography database is in the `bibtex` format. I can't seem to get the references to print properly when I use `\completepublications`. `\placepublications` seems to work fine though.

Here is my minimum working example:

```
\usemodule[bib]
\usemodule[bibltx]
\setupbibtex[database=xampl]
\setuppublications[numbering=yes] % Show reference numbers in the generated list.
\starttext
\chapter{One}
As \cite[lat2cont] already indicated, bibtex is a \LaTeX-centric program.
\completepublications
%\placepublications
\stoptext
```

Here is my `bib` file:

```
@article{lat2cont,
    title   = {Latex to context},
    author  = {Abc},
    journal = {Xyz},
    year    = 2003,
    pages   = {603-619},
}
```

My MWE is more or less the same as that on the [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Bibliography).

`\completepublications` doesn't generate the references and just prints `[[error]]` in place of the citations and nothing under the references heading. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Substitute

```
\completepublications
```

with

```
\completepublications [criterium=all]
```

That will display all references. To display only the cited references use

```
\completepublications [criterium=text]
```

A side note: When you use MkIV (when you compile with `context file` instead of `texexec file`) you don't need the first two `\usemodule` lines. The code is integrated in the system core.

Another thing I stumbled upon is the use of `\completepublications` in combination with PDF bookmarks. The `\completepublications` produces the PDF bookmark *pubs*, which I almost always want to be replaced with *References*. In the following example I changed this.

```
\setupinteraction  [state=start]
\placebookmarks    [title, chapter] [force=yes]
\setupbibtex       [database=xampl]
\setuppublications [numbering=yes]

\starttext

\startchapter [title=One]
    As \cite[lat2cont] already indicated, bibtex is a \LaTeX-centric program.
\stopchapter

%\completepublications [criterium=text] % produces *pubs* as PDF bookmark
\starttitle [title=References]          % produces *References* as PDF bookmark
    \placepublications
\stoptitle

\stoptext
```

Comment: The `citerium=all` option prints out all the entries in the `bib` file. I usually use a single large `bib` database for all my work, so this option is not really suitable for me. I know I'm nitpicking here, but is there a way to get only the cited references in the style `\completepublications` prints it out.

Comment: It's not nitpicking, you're totally right. I changed my answer to only display the cited publications.

Comment: A quick follow-up question. How did you know about this option? Because I can't fin it in the [documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/context/bib/bibmod-doc.pdf) for the `bib` module. It only lists the options `all` and `cite` for `criterium`.

Comment: `text` is a valid value for lists like `\placelist[<some_list]` or `\placecontent`. Since publications are also just a list, it should take the same options.

Comment: Thanks for the question and the answers; I pondered about the problem for some days 'till I found that you can use the "text" argument!