# How can I use bibtex with google docs to produce RTF files for journal submission?

Tags: bibtex

Our project quite happily uses google docs to collaborately edit documents and store a bunch of them. We also quite happily use ConTeXt to produce [internal publication](http://www.fedarch.org/wordpress/mission/project-reports/)s in pdf format.

Unfortunately, when dealing with humanities journals, the requirement is "all Word, all the time."

Therefore, given that we have a trival output of a BibTeX citations DB in Mendeley (that also provides for group collaboration on citations), a fair amount of ConTeXt expertise and awareness in the group, and a document in google docs, what is a simple and reliable workflow to somehow use BibTeX citations to do in-line citations in *arbitrary* [journal format X](http://www.australianarchaeology.com/our-journal/notes-to-contributors/) (::muttermuttermutter::) and optimally, basic header and footnote typesetting?

Comment: I will fully accept answers of "don't do it this way" so long as they can provide a good gesture in the direction that does work.

Comment: Have you contacted the Editors? Sometimes on-line guidelines 
are... incomplete. If a format only is the matter, 
you can construct a word `.doc` file out of raster images of your `pdf` pages, (kind of a sarcastic action). It was mentioned recently on this site, that Word 2013 is capable of importing `.pdf`.

Comment: Yes, we have. We also have something like 5 *different* journals, conferences, and other cited nonsense that require Word/rtf that we'll need to submit other things to. All with... incomplete guidelines. Apparently they don't trust authors to ... typeset.

Comment: Okay, not going to put this in an answer cause there has got to be a better solution but: [Bibtex for word](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/perl/index.html) seems to maybe kinda sorta suggest that this works?

Answer (score 1):

`bibtex` is not your main problem in this work flow, but rather `context`.  Once your document is at final stage you can remove the `bibtex` part of the compilation by including the output `.bbl` file in your source code.  For example, using the setup of [References in ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42239/15925)

`orig-file.tex`:

```
\setupinteraction  [state=start]
\placebookmarks    [title, chapter] [force=yes]
\setupbibtex       [database=xampl]
\setuppublications [numbering=yes]

\starttext

\startchapter [title=One]
    As \cite[lat2cont] already indicated, bibtex is a \LaTeX-centric program.
\stopchapter

%\completepublications [criterium=text] % produces *pubs* as PDF bookmark
\starttitle [title=References]          % produces *References* as PDF bookmark
    \placepublications
\stoptitle

\stoptext
```

with `xampl.bib`

```
@article{lat2cont,
    title   = {Latex to context},
    author  = {Abc},
    journal = {Xyz},
    year    = 2003,
    pages   = {603-619},
}
```

compiles producing `orig-file.bbl`

```
\setuppublicationlist[samplesize={Abc03},totalnumber=1]

\startpublication[k=lat2cont,t=article,
a={{Abc}},y=2003,
n=1,s=Abc03]
\artauthor[]{}[]{}{Abc}
\pubyear{2003}
\arttitle{Latex to context}
\journal{Xyz}
\pages{603-619}
\stoppublication
```

Pasting this into your original file and commenting out the reference to the external database, we get `new-file.tex` which compiles without `bibtex`:

```
\setupinteraction  [state=start]
\placebookmarks    [title, chapter] [force=yes]
%\setupbibtex       [database=xampl]
\setuppublications [numbering=yes]
\setuppublicationlist[samplesize={Abc03},totalnumber=1]

\startpublication[k=lat2cont,t=article,
a={{Abc}},y=2003,
n=1,s=Abc03]
\artauthor[]{}[]{}{Abc}
\pubyear{2003}
\arttitle{Latex to context}
\journal{Xyz}
\pages{603-619}
\stoppublication



\starttext

\startchapter [title=One]
    As \cite[lat2cont] already indicated, bibtex is a \LaTeX-centric program.
\stopchapter

%\completepublications [criterium=text] % produces *pubs* as PDF bookmark
\starttitle [title=References]          % produces *References* as PDF bookmark
    \placepublications
\stoptitle

\stoptext
```

Now you need a `context` to `rtf/word` converter - but the [FAQ](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/FAQ#How_can_I_convert_a_document_into_RTF_or_HTML.3F) suggests this does not exist.  If you use LaTeX then there are converter programs.